# re-connect to postgreSQL as a new user , after login

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm using postgreSQL 9.1. I created four roles/users on the db, each one has different rights on different tables.

When someone try to login, php connects to the db as "guest"(the first role/user) like

```
$conn = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=mydb user=guest password=guest")or die('no connection, sorry');
```

Guest can only "select" from the "users" table, to check for a login. After a succesfull login, I want to re-connect the user to the db, according to an int named "level", on the "users" table. If "level" found in the table is 1 I want to re-connect the user as "low" role/user, like

```
$conn = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=mydb user=low password=low")or die('no connection, sorry');
```

"Low" role/user can only insert and update on some tables.

And subsequently for the other roles/users. If "level" found on the users table is 2, connect as "mid" (can insert/update/delete), if it is 3 connect as "high" (the superuser).

Briefly, it's like : connect as "guest" so you can "select" and validate the login > Login succesfull > According to "level", re-connect as "low", so you can insert/update OR as "mid" so you can insert/update/delete OR as "high" so, superuser.

How can i do that? To re-connect after a succesfull login, so the user gets the rights he needs, so he can perform the right actions?

Thank you

Comment: After successful login disconnect from the current db and reconnect to the appropriate permission level.

Comment: Pass the db resourse to pg_close, http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-close.php

Answer (score 1):

The simple thing is to GRANT USAGE on the roles you want the guest user to change privileges to:

```
GRANT ROLE my_app_user1 TO guest;
```

Then after successful authentication you can just:

```
SET ROLE my_app_user1;
```

You can run authentication checks in the mean time.